# Reset VirtualBox Linux password on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: linux, boot, debian, passwords, grub

I'm trying to reset a password for a Linux (Debian) virtual box on our Windows 2012 R2 server.  The password I was given doesn't work but I do have the administrator password for the server and can access Hyper V. I'm not techie but inherited this system and need access to that virtual box.

"If you forgot your root password for your debian server use the following procedure to reset."  Will this work?  If so, how do I reboot the virtual box and get to the GRUB menu?

"Boot to the GRUB menu. Then, press  (for edit) before Linux has a chance to boot.

Using your keyboard arrow keys, move the cursor down a line or so, and press  (for edit) again, you should now be on the kernel line, and press  to go out to the very end of that line. Now hit the spacebar once, if necessary, to add a space, and then add one of the folllowing:

```
init=/bin/bash
```

or

```
init=/bin/sh
```

Then press , and you're back at the kernel line, press  (for boot) and the computer will proceed to boot to a root prompt.

At this point, the root file system is still mounted read-only, so enter the following command:

```
mount -n -o remount,rw /
```

Then type:

```
passwd
```

Enter your new password. Retype if asked to confirm.
Then restart the machine by typing:

```
reboot
```

Now you should be able to login with your new root password as required."

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The guide you cites sound just about correct. I, for one, did such thing more than once. So, what's your actual problem then?

Comment: I so not see the kernal line to input the commands.

Comment: I finally got it.  Now to secure it from past admins.  That should be easy.

Comment: You have you found it in the GRUB menu, have you?

Comment: Yes almost at the end right before silent.  It never said Kernel